I am getting this issue while I used pay 1.0.0 for the apple pay in flutter also I use flutter 3.3.9 and SDK is 2.18.5
Error: Member not found: 'minimumButonWidth'.
    double width = RawApplePayButton.minimumButonWidth,
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay-1.1.0/lib/src/widgets/apple_pay_button.dart:42:43: Error: Member not found: 'minimumButonWidth'.
  })  : assert(width >= RawApplePayButton.minimumButonWidth),

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am getting this issue while I used pay 1.0.0 for the apple pay in flutter also I use flutter 3.3.9 and SDK is 2.18.5.

Issue: https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues/244
You're saying that you use the 1.0.0 version, which is not true. Your log says that the current version is 1.1.0. Why is that? Because of the caret syntax(^) in the version.
Solution:

Try to upgrade to 1.1.2(pay: ^1.1.2).
If you want to use specifically v1.0.0, then remove the caret symbol, so that the package manager wont try to get the latest compatible version(do pay: 1.0.0 instead of pay: ^1.0.0).

More about the caret syntax: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages
